# Is there a fixed length version of MySQL's CHAR data type that can store more than 255 characters?

Tags: php, mysql, char

I know about `VARCHAR`, `TEXT`, etc. but I'm hoping for something that has a fixed width because I value the boost in efficiency, even if it's minor. I can't seem to find anything in the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/char.html), and my only other option is to split a message into pieces and store each in a separate column.

Comment: Not clear your question. If you want to store more than 255 characters why not use `TEXT` type? If you need a fixed width at 255 why not use `VARCHAR(255)`?

Comment: @sonnb: maybe because TEXT is not stored alongside other fields, and accessing it is in fact slower?

Comment: @Mchl: Yes. It's slower than `VARCHAR` type with specific length. But for a unspecific length field it's a good choice.

Comment: I'm sorry what? You can't have VARCHAR with unspecified length...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no such datatype. Did you actually measure if using CHAR in place of VARCHAR gives you any measurable performance gain? Remember what they say about premature optimization?

Splitting message into many columns and then stitching it together will probably be slower, than any increase in speed gained from using CHAR instead of VARCHAR.

Comment: Ah, ok. Thanks for the help. I know that premature optimisation isn't good; I was hoping to find a data type that fit my needs so I could design the table as a fixed-width table. I know that's premature, but I'd also read that fixed-width tables were more stable and didn't fragment as much. 

Thank you!

Comment: Fragmentation will only occur, if you UPDATE a row so that new message is longer than the old one. Fragmentation also occurs in many different situations (like deleting rows), and you should look up documentation of your storage engine on how to deal with it.